# How to find the amount of equal characters that are next to eachother in a string?

Tags: python, string, count

i just started using python and im a noob.
this is an example of the string i have to work with "--+-+++----------------+-+"
The program needs to find whats the longest ++ "chain", so how many times does + appear, when they are next to eachother. I dont really know how to explain this, but i need it to find that chain of 3 + smybols, so i can print that the longest + chain contains 3 + symbols.

Comment: One approach (and there are many) is to step through each item, one-by-one, and count the number of repeats until a change occurs. You need to attempt to write some code to do this and present your code. Then we can try to help fix it if it doesn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Longest sequence of consecutive duplicates in a python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53035271/longest-sequence-of-consecutive-duplicates-in-a-python-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
a = "--+-+++----------------+-+"


count = 0
most = 0
for x in range(len(a)):

    if a[x] == "+":
        count+=1
    else:
        count = 0

    if count > most:
        most = count


print(f"longest + chain includes {most} symbols")
```

there might be a better way but it's more self explanatory

Comment: This worked, thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It uses regular expressions and a list comprehension, so you may need to read about them.
But the idea is to find all the + chains, calculate their lengths and get the maximum length

```
import re

s = '+++----------------+-+'

occurs = re.findall('\++',s)
print(max([len(i) for i in occurs]))
```

Output:

```
3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to specify "one or more `+` characters". The character for specifying this kind of repetition in a regex is itself `+`, so to specify the actual `+` character you have to escape it.

```
haystack = "--+-+++----------------+-+"
needle = re.compile(r"\++")
```

Now we can use `findall` to find all the occurrences of this pattern in the original string, and `max` to find the longest of these.

```
longest = max(len(x) for x in needle.findall(haystack))
```

If you instead need the *position* of the longest sequence in the target string, you can use:

```
pos =  haystack.index(max(needle.findall(haystack), key=len))
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to iterate over the string one character at a time. When the character is the same as the last add one to a counter and each time the character is different to the previous the count can be restarted.

```
s = "--+-+++----------------+-+"

p = s[0]
max, count = 0
for c in s:
    if c == p:
        count = count + 1
    else:
        count = 0
    if count > max:
        max = count
    p = c
```

s is the string, c is the character being checked, p is previous character, count is the counter, and max is the highest found value,

Answer (score 0):

If the only other character in your string is a minus sign, you can split the string on the minus sign and get maximum length of the resulting substrings:

```
a = "--+-+++----------------+-+"

r = max(map(len,a.split('-')))
print(r) # 3
```